# Calculating the damage in a game

Tags: calculus, game-theory

I'm trying to figure out how the damage is calculated in a game, but have been unable to. I'm not sure if this is the right platform to ask this. If not, pls let me know in the comments and I'll delete the question right away.

I have tested it with 3 characters, fighting 2 other characters separately.

```
DMG        damage done to defender  
ATTACK     attack power of the attacker  
ARMOR      total amount of armor of the defender  
LVL        lvl of the defender
REDUCTION  total amount of dmg reduced (ATTACK - DMG)
```

The data is as follows:

```
          DMG     ATTACK    ARMOR    LVL  REDUCTION
Norma    9.142    13.342    1.064    160    4.200
OD-01    4.305     6.284    1.064    160    1.979
Vesas    3.222     4.703    1.064    160    1.481

Norma    9.674    13.342    1.039    180    3.668
OD-01    4.556     6.284    1.039    180    1.728
```

Someone pointed out the formula should roughly be like:

```
reduction in % = ARMOR / (200 + LVL * 20)
```

But this formula is off by a small margin and was hoping I could find the exact formula to calculate the damage. Anyone an idea how the `DMG` is calculated from `ATTACK, ARMOR and LVL`?

Comment: Your tag game theory made me cry in laughter. You should post to gaming stack exchange https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah I didn't know that existed. thanks! Ill delete this in 40 min (can't post a new question yet, and it doesn't seem people go there to calculate things :o)

Comment: $\text{ REDUCTION } = \text{ ATTACK } / (2 \times \text{LVL})$ gives a much better result, but still is not quite right. However, the data here isn't varied enough to be able to deduce much.